# push all element of array in subdocument while saving document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to push elements of array to create subdocument,

my schema

```
var chatGroup = new Schema({

name : {
    type : String,
    default : null 
},
members: {
    type : [subSchemaForMember]
},
```

}, { collection: 'chatGroup' });

var subSchemaForMember = new Schema({

```
user_id   : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'user'}},{_id : false});
```

my query to save document is

```
var chatGroup = new ChatGroup({

        name       : req.body.name,
        image      : req.body.image,
        created_by : req.body.celebrity_id,
        $pushAll   : {'members' : req.body.members}
    })
```

where req.body.memebers = ['someid','someid','someid']

Please help I want to do it without any loop

Comment: is `subSchemaForMembers` just a string? That's what you're representing at least when you say that `req.body.members = ['someId', 'someId', 'someId']`?

Comment: in other words, is it `members: { type: [String] }` ?

Comment: members : [{ user_id   : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'user'} ,}] its like this subdocument

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you actually saving the document, only calling `new` on the constructor. You need to explicitly call save. on the object after you construct it. For the documentation on creating documents, see here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html.

Also, the use of `$pushAll` only applies when you have an object already in mongodb, which has existing values, and you want to retain those values and push additional values onto the array (so in your example you can simply assign the array to `members`).

Also of note is that the current mongoose documentation indicates that `$pushAll` is deprecated and you should be using `$push` together with `$each`, but the same rules apply, see here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-multiple-values-to-an-array

Comment: Are you saving the model? Your example doesnt do that, and as i said im not sure you should use push at all on a new object. Just assign the array of ids.